# Successive Derivatives of Advection Equation

Tags: derivatives, partial-differential-equations, vector-analysis

I am trying to evaluate higher order derivatives from the constant coefficient advection equation given as

$\frac{\partial c}{\partial t} = -\mathbf{u} \cdot \nabla c, \quad \mathbf{u} = (u,v,w)$.

I was hoping to consider this in two ways, the first is to evaluate higher order derivatives in terms of $x$ and $y$ (for the 2-D case) such as

$ \frac{\partial^{2}c}{\partial x^{2}} = \frac{1}{u^{2}} \bigg( \frac{\partial^{2}c}{\partial t^{2}} + 2v \frac{\partial^{2}c}{\partial t \partial y} + v^{2} \frac{\partial^{2}c}{\partial y^{2}} \bigg) $

$ \frac{\partial^{2}c}{\partial y^{2}} = \frac{1}{v^{2}} \bigg( \frac{\partial^{2}c}{\partial t^{2}} + 2u \frac{\partial^{2}c}{\partial t \partial x} + u^{2} \frac{\partial^{2}c}{\partial x^{2}} \bigg) $

For the third-order and higher order terms, I would imagine that it looks like some sort of binomial expansion but it gets prohibitively tedious to show this. Alternatively, I was hoping to use vector calculus to tackle this which gave me the following expression for the second and third temporal derivatives.

$\frac{\partial^{2}c}{\partial t^{2}} = \mathbf{u}\cdot (\nabla (\nabla c) \cdot \mathbf{u}) $

$\frac{\partial^{3}c}{\partial t^{3}} = -\mathbf{u} \cdot ( \nabla (\nabla(\nabla c) \cdot \mathbf{u}) \cdot \mathbf{u})$

Which as we can see becomes progressively more tedious. However, in the 1-D case, we can see a very neat expression for higher-order derivatives

$\frac{\partial^{n}c}{\partial x^{n}} = (-1)^{n}\frac{1}{u^{n}}\frac{\partial^{n}c}{\partial t^{n}}, \quad n\in\mathbb{Z}^{+}$

Hence my question is: Is there a neat way of obtaining higher-order derivatives that is water-tight. Thanks for the help!

Comment: If $\mathbf{u}$ is a constant, then $\partial_t^n c=(-\mathbf{u} \cdot \nabla)^n c$